# Apache ENVVARS not loading

Tags: apache-2.4, source

My problem originated from my website not loading on a almost-fresh install of Debian and an ISPConfig server, Apache and MariaDB only. It would resolve, but not loaded after site loaded once completely. Running `apache2ctl status` indicated returned that many of the Apache workers were stuck in  "L" or logging state. I emptied all the logs, but to no avail. Randomly, I just ran `apache2` on the terminal and saw a bunch of warnings indicating that none of the variables specified in `/etc/apache2/envvars` were set.

I generally use `service apache2 restart` to restart Apache. After searching the web, I found that sometimes one command may not load the `envvars` file. So I tried restarting with:
`service apache2 restart`
`apache2ctl restart`
`/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

None of these load the `envvars`. Sourcing the file (`source /etc/apache2/envvars`), makes it work, but only for a while, and then it stops working for a reason I can't determine. Checking the restart script, it seems `envvars` are accounted for.

Ideally I would not have to aplly the temporary fix by sourcing the file every time. Why is it not automatically running?

Answer (score 1):

you may have to do:

```
apache2ctl stop && apache2ctl start
```

**or**

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 stop && /etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

as only "restart" doesn't seem to load the envvars file that is generated from `envvars-std.in`.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this bug since I have exactly the same problem with my webserver. Once in a while I need to do `source /etc/apache2/envvars` in order to get it working again. I also use apache2 in conjunction with mariadb on Debian (Jessie).

Does anyone know how this could happen and what can be done about it to fix the problem? The weird thing is, I don't have this problem on other webservers.

Comment: Since this is more of a "me, too!" it belongs more as a comment than as an answer/solution to the OP's posting.

Answer (score 0):

My fix was to change from `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash` inside `/etc/init.d/apache2` . This might help you as well :)

Comment: Obviously, this doesn't work. (Yes, tested)